# How to use libraries with npm?

Tags: javascript, html, shared-libraries

I'm new to javascript and would like to include moment.js (or any other library) in a project but I don't know how to set up my project so that I can import from the library.
I've set up my html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Using Libraries</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my script:

```
import moment from "moment";

console.log(moment());
```

then I ran

```
npm install moment --save
```

in the terminal and got my node_modules, package.json, package-lock.json. When I run my html I still get a CORS error:

```
Access to script at 'file:///home/daliborp/repos/gittest/script.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
```

What am I doing wrong?
How would I go about using moment.js (or any other library) with npm?

In a tutorial I did with webpack running the command in terminal did the trick, but without webpack I have no clue how to import libraries.
Any suggestions, maybe a good tutorial on the topic?

Comment: *"When I run my html I still get a CORS error."* - How are you testing this and what is the error?

Comment: When I open the html in the browser I get this error: Access to script at 'file:///home/daliborp/repos/gittest/script.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Comment: There are a great many other duplicates as well.  Basically, the problem is that you're trying to run a web application without a web server.  Opening the HTML file from the file system is *very* limiting.  You'll want to start serving your pages from a development server instead.

Answer (score 0):

first think first your need to setup your project . like "npm init" and create one javascript file like "app.js". open your terminal and go to your project path using CD command and type command on terminal, npm install moment --save . app.js file do open and type code "const moment = require("moment");"

and then print console.log(moment());

Comment: When I do that I get Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at script.js:1:16